# storage and post notification permission in android 13

Tags: android, android-studio, android-13

when i did some changes  to the app to target api level 33 , but in my case what is happening when user already granted the permission for read write images in old app , when they download the update , again it asking for read read images and write images permission , i want that it should not ask again

changes i am doing

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
)<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
     

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=32) {
      
            requestRuntimePermission();
         
            //
        }
        else  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) { //  10 and above devices
            if (permissionGranted(MainActivity.this, "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")) {
                //launchMainScreen();
            }
        } else if (hasPermission(PERMISSIONS_STORAGE[0]) && hasPermission(PERMISSIONS_STORAGE[1])) {
         //   launchMainScreen();
            startGridActivity();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }



   private void requestRuntimePermission() {
    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_MEDIA_IMAGES) == 
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        startGridActivity();
    }
    else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,READ_MEDIA_IMAGES)) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "show setting five", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("The App requires write Externel storage  permission for particular features to work as expected.").
                setTitle("Permission Required").
                setCancelable(false).
                setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog2, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,new String[]{ READ_MEDIA_IMAGES},REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                        dialog2.dismiss();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",((dialog2, which) -> dialog2.dismiss()));
        builder.show();
    }
    else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{ READ_MEDIA_IMAGES},REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
}


 public boolean permissionGranted(final Activity activity, String str) {
    final boolean[] zArr = {false};
    Dexter.withActivity(activity).withPermission(str).withListener(new PermissionListener() {
        public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse permissionGrantedResponse) {
            zArr[0] = true;
            startGridActivity();
        }

        public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse permissionDeniedResponse) {

            if (permissionDeniedResponse.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                showSettingsDialog(activity);
                Log.d("HELLO", "onPermissionDenied:1 ");
                Toast.makeText(activity, "showSetting2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
            /* else {
                activity.onBackPressed();
            }*/
        }

        public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permissionRequest, PermissionToken permissionToken) {
            showPermissionDialog(activity, permissionToken);
            Log.d("HELLO", "onPermissionDenied:2 ");
            Toast.makeText(activity, "showSetting3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).check();
    return zArr[0];
}
```

In production how they are doing

```
 if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                if (permissionGranted(MainActivity.this, "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")) {

                }

                /*if (!hasPermission(PERMISSIONS_STORAGE_FOR10[0])) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE_FOR10, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LaunchActivity.this, GridSelectionActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                }*/
            } else {
                if (hasPermission(PERMISSIONS_STORAGE[0]) && hasPermission(PERMISSIONS_STORAGE[1])) {
                    startGridActivity();
                } else {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }


            }

            break;
```